# itemChanged() on QStandardItemModel triggered when data hasn't changed

Tags: qt, qt4.8, qstandarditemmodel

I have the following connect line:

```
connect(my_QStandardItemModel ,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),
    this,SLOT(cellEditEndedCalled(QStandardItem*)));
```

For some reason whenever I go into edit mode on a cell inside my table (double click) and click on another cell, `cellEditEndedCalled()` is being called even though I didn't make any changes to my data.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

EDIT:
Tried with `dataChanged(...)` instead of `itemChanged(...)` but the slot is still being called.

Implementation of my_QStandardItemModel :

```
class my_QStandardItemModel :public QStandardItemModel
{
    typedef QStandardItemModel baseClass;
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    my_QStandardItemModel ();
    virtual ~my_QStandardItemModel ();

...
```

Not overwriting any signals afterwards.

Comment: You might override `my_QStandardItemModel::setData()` function of your model and do nothing if the new value is equal to existing one. Otherwise call parent class function, i.e. `QStandardItemModel::setData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the signal `itemChanged` is not the correct for your situation. `QStandardItemModel` inherits another singal form `QAbstractItemModel`

```
    void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const 
QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int> ())
```

that emits with `QModelIndex` information on the index where changes occured : your cell.

you need to connect that signal to your slot (to be modified to match new signal signature).

Why the `itemChanged` signal is emitted even you did not modify the data: because that signal emits when you change your item **NOT** the data in it.

Comment: same effect, data didn't change but the method was still called

Comment: @bardao, what is your view? is it `QTableview` ?

Comment: yes I am using a  `QTableView`, should I check the signals on that one instead?

Comment: @bardao, no thats fine, I am using the signal with `QSqlTableModel` and it works fine. could you update your code using _new signal Slot syntax_

Comment: would that work in Qt4.8? I am getting an error accessing protected memeber in `QAbstractItemModel` which I don't know the source of.

Comment: @bardao, not sure, you have to check with which version the new syntax came. are you modifying `setEditStrategy` for your itemmodel .. share code for creating the `my_QStandardItemModel`

Comment: I didn't modify any existing methods, I just added to it. I shared the creation in the original post.